# How to fix Firebase warning "you're using the development build of the Firebase"

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I found several answers here about how to fix this warning in my Vue app, but even when I follow the standard advice given I still get the warning. Here's how I import Firebase:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The warning about a development build is logged when you're using `firebase.js`, which includes the SDKs for all Firebase products in a single file.

If you're still getting that warning, you're very likely still using `firebase.js` in one of your files, or in a build artifact.